# Standard purpose of favorites

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I am wondering if my behavior regarding favorites is typical.  More importantly, if it isn't typical, does my behavior conflict with an internal metric designed to reward favorite'd questions?

I mark a question as a favorite for a few reasons:

A -- I find the question/answer(s) remarkable enough that coming back to them time and time again is of benefit to me.

B -- I am waiting to see if a sub-par quality question is going to be revised enough for me to come back and answer it.  Either way, I eventually remove my favorite.

C -- I have answered a question (of any quality) and am wanting to be notified of any competing answers.

Situations B and C are the most common for me and they typically mean I will go back and remove my favorite star later; I don't remove it because the quality of the question degraded, I merely don't want to be notified any longer.

Even stranger, I am often favoriting questions that are rather low-quality (reason B) making me wonder if low-quality posts are being rewarded via some invisible metric because I (at least temporarily) have given it what looks like a stamp of approval akin to an up-vote.

I suppose the feature being called "Favorite" makes me confused because most of the questions I select are not my favorite.  Am I accidentally messing with an invisible metric that is drawing attention to posts when that isn't desired behavior?

Comment: Favorited questions might get the OP some badges (at 25 or 100 favorites), but that's about it. I use them in a similar way as you do. Not necessarily to indicate that they are excellent.

Comment: So there aren't any invisible metrics that I am not aware of?  (I figured some of you in Meta might know more about this.)

Comment: Oh, we're keeping an eye on you. And yes, we saw when you did that thing that you did. You know what I mean.... ;) Nah, nothing that I'm aware of. No harm done, I'd say.

Comment: "Bookmark" might be a better name for that feature, since that's basically its function. You're not using it wrong - there really isn't a "wrong" way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nah, you're using it fine. It's basically for any situation where you'd like to follow or bookmark the post.

> Even stranger, I am often favoriting questions that are rather low-quality (reason B) making me wonder if low-quality posts are being rewarded via some invisible metric because I (at least temporarily) have given it what looks like a stamp of approval akin to an up-vote.

Nope. With enough favorites, the user can get a badge, but that's it.